# Does Decorator pattern have a disadvantage for "bulky" classes with many fields?

Tags: java, design-patterns

So we all know about the good 'ol Decorator pattern, especially I couldn't find any cons as such over Internet. But there is one big one I could think of:

If your base class happens to be *bulky*(holds like 50 fields) and you decide to decorate it:

```
public class BulkyBaseClass {

    // 50 fields
    //...
}

class Decorator extends BulkyBaseClass{

    private BulkyBaseClass mBase;

    public Decorator(BulkyBaseClass bulkyBaseClass){
        this.mBase = bulkyBaseClass;
    }

    // Some overrides to decorate the composed base class
}
```

Then, can't we see here that most of the fields of the decorator itself are useless and we are really only interested in the fields of the class being decorated and that leads to a big memory footprint?

To me, that's a big disadvantage. Isn't it?

Comment: If "_your base class happens to be bulky_" then it should not be a single class. A class with 50 fields is a **massive** red flag.

Comment: @BoristheSpider : But being an Android Developer, you will find some of the fundamental classes such as View class as quite bulky and I got to see decorator pattern being applied there(some answer on SO). I immediately got alarmed as to adapt that answer or not

Answer (score 3):

Yes, direct use of decorator pattern does have a disadvantage for classes with multiple fields, because their majority remain unused in the derived class that wraps `mBase` instance.

However, the disadvantage stems from inheriting implementation, rather than inheriting an interface. Therefore, you can easily fix it by extracting an interface from `BulkyBaseClass`, and using it inside the `Decorator` class:

```
interface LeanInterface {
    void method1();
    int method2();
}
class BulkyBaseClass implements LeanInterface {
    ...
}
class Decorator implements LeanInterface {
    private BulkyBaseClass mBase;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not a problem of decorating, but yet another **problem of inheritance**.

Decorate through interfaces whenever you can, like this:

```java
public interface Connection {
    void connect();

    void write(byte[] data) throws IOException;
}

public final class ReconnectingConnection implements Connection {
    private final Connection delegate;

    public ReconnectingConnection(Connection delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    ...
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] data) {
        ...reconnect on exception from delegate.write()...
    }
}
```

Using own implementation on interfaces makes sure you're not actually coupling to a specific implementation, and also avoids problems with some implementations being too large.

When faced with external classes that you want to decorate this obviously is not always possible.